# statnet network missing vertexes

Tags: r, graph, sna

I am using network claas from statnet in R.

They have some tutorials in statistical software journal. So I founf information about 'na' attribute for vertexes and edges. But I can not find any information in manual or the Internet about this for vertexes ( it still some about edges ). This attribute is logical and if `TRUE` then vertex is unobserved. And when I print network class vertexes and edges do not have that attribute, but tutorial says that it is default attribute.

Does anybode know what happend to this attribute or it just me can not find info.

Answer (score 1):

The network package supports a missingness ('na') attribute for both vertices and edges, but does not seem to provide many functions for working with vertex missingness, and missingness of vertices is not reported by print.network()

```
> test<-network.initialize(3)
> list.vertex.attributes(test)
[1] "na"           "vertex.names"
> test%v%'na'
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```